# Will exception be thrown when @@Error is set?

Tags: c#, sql-server

As I read in the documentation, the @@Error global variable is set when an exception occurs. Eg: foreign key violation and so.

Let's say I have a sample procedure:

```
Create Procedure someName
Begin

    Insert Into something...
    return @@Error

End
```

I want to know when an exception occurs will the return `@@Error` be executed? or will the control come in my `catch` block in my C# code? The `@@Error` really confuses me. If error isn't thrown when foreign key violates then why do we have Try Catch in Sql Server?

Comment: Well worth a read: http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in T-SQL an error doesn't terminate execution.  Try-catch was added in newer versions so you can have better handling of errors, I guess.

Comment: So what will happen if I have Begin Try and End Try and Begin Catch..End Catch? If Error is thrown will the control never reach catch block and just continue execution to the next after error is thrown?

Comment: Actually an error _can_ terminate execution, ignore try/catch blocks, and even terminate the connection if it's severe enough. See the documentation on the `RAISERROR` command [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx)

Comment: @Bridge, he is talking about an error such as trying to insert a null into a NOT NULL field.  Raiserror explicitly terminates execution.

Comment: @kristianp just clarifying on `in T-SQL an error doesn't terminate execution` - just a bit vague for my liking ;-)